# How to move a chess piece with a numpy array?

Tags: python, numpy

So for the past several days I've been trying to get my chess engine working in a numpy array. I've already created this entire thing in string base, but it won't work, because of the overall with the numpy array. I've built this in pygame. So I'm using the latest version of numpy and pygame.
The code:

```
import sys
import numpy as np
import pygame as p

BOARD_WIDTH = 512
BOARD_HEIGHT = 512
DIMENSION = 8  # dimensions of a chess board are 8x8
SQ_SIZE = 512 // DIMENSION
MAX_FPS = 60  # for animations later on
screen = p.display.set_mode((BOARD_WIDTH, BOARD_HEIGHT))
IMAGES = {}
class GameState():
    def __init__(self):
        # board is 8x8 2D List, each element of the list has 2 characters
        # initial character == colour (b,w)
        # second character == piece
        # R == rook, N == knight, B == bishop, Q == Queen, K == king, P == pawn
        # -- == empty space
        self.board = [
            ["bR", "bN", "bB", "bQ", "bK", "bB", "bN", "bR"],
            ["bp", "bp", "bp", "bp", "bp", "bp", "bp", "bp"],
            ["--", "--", "--", "--", "--", "--", "--", "--"],
            ["--", "--", "--", "--", "--", "--", "--", "--"],
            ["--", "--", "--", "--", "--", "--", "--", "--"],
            ["--", "--", "--", "--", "--", "--", "--", "--"],
            ["wp", "wp", "wp", "wp", "wp", "wp", "wp", "wp"],
            ["wR", "wN", "wB", "wQ", "wK", "wB", "wN", "wR"]
        ]

        self.lookup = {
            "--": 0,
            "wK": 1, "wQ": 2, "wR": 3, "wB": 4, "wN": 5, "wp": 6,
            "bK": 7, "bQ": 8, "bR": 9, "bB": 10, "bN": 11, "bp": 12
        }
        self.compute_board = np.array([[self.lookup[p] for p in row] for row in self.board])
        print(self.compute_board)

        self.whiteToMove = True
        self.moveLog = []

    def makeMove(self, move):
        self.compute_board[move.start_row][move.start_col] == 0
        self.compute_board[move.end_row][move.end_col] = move.piece_moved
        self.moveLog.append(move)
        print(self.moveLog)
        self.whiteToMove = not self.whiteToMove


class Move:
    # in chess, fields on the board are described by two symbols, one of them being number between 1-8 (which is corresponding to rows)
    # and the second one being a letter between a-f (corresponding to columns), in order to use this notation we need to map our [row][col] coordinates
    # to match the ones used in the original chess game
    ranks_to_rows = {"1": 7, "2": 6, "3": 5, "4": 4,
                 "5": 3, "6": 2, "7": 1, "8": 0}
    rows_to_ranks = {v: k for k, v in ranks_to_rows.items()}
    files_to_cols = {"a": 0, "b": 1, "c": 2, "d": 3,
                 "e": 4, "f": 5, "g": 6, "h": 7}
    cols_to_files = {v: k for k, v in files_to_cols.items()}

    def __init__(self, start_square, end_square, compute_board):
        self.start_row = start_square[0]
        self.start_col = start_square[1]
        self.end_row = end_square[0]
        self.end_col = end_square[1]
        self.piece_moved = compute_board[self.start_row][self.start_col]
        self.piece_captured = compute_board[self.end_row][self.end_col]

    def getChessNotation(self):
        return self.getRankFile(self.start_row, self.start_col + self.getRankFile(self.end_row, self.end_col))

    def getRankFile(self, r, c):
        return self.cols_to_files[c] + self.rows_to_ranks[r]


def main():
    p.init()
    square_selected = ()  # no square is selected initially, this will keep track of the last click of the user (tuple(row,col))
    player_clicks = []  # this will keep track of player clicks (two tuples)
    gs = GameState()
    clock = p.time.Clock()
    loadImages()  # only do this once, before the while loop
    running = True

    while running:

        for e in p.event.get():
            if e.type == p.QUIT:
                p.quit()
                sys.exit()
            # mouse handler
            elif e.type == p.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                location = p.mouse.get_pos()  # (x, y) location of the mouse
                col = location[0] // SQ_SIZE
                row = location[1] // SQ_SIZE
                if square_selected == (row, col) or col >= 8:  # user clicked the same square twice
                    square_selected = ()  # deselect
                    player_clicks = []  # clear clicks
                else:
                    square_selected = (row, col)
                    player_clicks.append(square_selected)  # append for both 1st and 2nd click
                if len(player_clicks) == 2:  # after 2nd click
                    move = Move(player_clicks[0], player_clicks[1], gs.compute_board)
                    # print(move.getChessNotation())
                    gs.makeMove(move)
                    square_selected = ()
                    player_clicks = []

        drawGameState(screen, gs.board)

        clock.tick(MAX_FPS)
        p.display.update()


def loadImages():
    pieces = ['wp', 'wR', 'wN', 'wB', 'wK', 'wQ', 'bp', 'bR', 'bN', 'bB', 'bK', 'bQ']
    for piece in pieces:
        IMAGES[piece] = p.transform.scale(p.image.load("images/" + piece + ".png"), (SQ_SIZE, SQ_SIZE))


# Note we can access an image by saying "IMAGES['wp']'


def drawGameState(screen, board):
    drawBoard(screen)  # draw squares on the board
    drawPieces(screen, board)


def drawBoard(screen):
    global colors
    colors = [p.Color("white"), p.Color("gray")]
    for r in range(DIMENSION):
        for c in range(DIMENSION):
            color = colors[((r + c) % 2)]
            p.draw.rect(screen, color, p.Rect(c * SQ_SIZE, r * SQ_SIZE, SQ_SIZE, SQ_SIZE))


def drawPieces(screen, board):
    for row in range(DIMENSION):
        for column in range(DIMENSION):
            piece = board[row][column]
            if piece != "--":
                screen.blit(IMAGES[piece], p.Rect(column * SQ_SIZE, row * SQ_SIZE, SQ_SIZE, SQ_SIZE))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

For loading images you can use the images from wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chess_piece first column to your right under 'Chess Pieces'.

The problem lies in the line: `self.compute_board[move.start_row][move.start_col] == 0` where the 0 is for the empty spaces on the numpy array for where the pieces can move to, but I haven't figured out the issue. I've tried finding the `type` of value the `move.start_row` and the `move.start_col` which is all `int`. I've tried `self.compute_board[move.start_row][move.start_col] == list(self.lookup.keys())[list(self.lookup.values()).index(0)]` which gives you `'--'` doesn't work.

But this work for the string verison. In the class `Move` you change all the `compute_board` and `self.compute_board` to `board` and `self.board`. And all the `self.compute_board` in the `makeMove` in class `GameState`. Also change the 0 in `self.compute_board[move.start_row][move.start_col] = 0` to `'--'`. And in the main function change the `gs.compute_board` in `move = Move(player_clicks[0], player_clicks[1], gs.compute_board)` to `gs.board`.

When all these changes have been made all the pieces move no problem. But when it comes to the numpy array I don't know.

The `self.compute_board` is the way I want to code all the moves out into a numpy array so when I have my chess ai running it doesn't get bogged down by the strings it has to run through.

I solved the issue the logic was working its just that when I was loading in the images I was not loading them in with the `compute_board` just the other board. I also had to change how I blited the images on the board. If you want to know how let me know.

So if you could help me I appreciate it a lot, and if you need more info let me know.

Comment: Could you give the exact error message/stack trace?

Comment: There is no error or anything it just simply doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

It was on how I load in my images.

Old way:

```
def loadImages():
    pieces = ['wp', 'wR', 'wN', 'wB', 'wK', 'wQ', 'bp', 'bR', 'bN', 'bB', 'bK', 'bQ']
    for piece in pieces:
        IMAGES[piece] = p.transform.scale(p.image.load("images/" + piece + ".png"), (SQ_SIZE, SQ_SIZE))
```

New way:

```
    lookup = {
    "--": 0,
    "wK": 1, "wQ": 2, "wR": 3, "wB": 4, "wN": 5, "wp": 6,
    "bK": 7, "bQ": 8, "bR": 9, "bB": 10, "bN": 11, "bp": 12
}


def loadImages():
    pieces = ['wp', 'wR', 'wN', 'wB', 'wK', 'wQ', 'bp', 'bR', 'bN', 'bB', 'bK', 'bQ']
    for piece in pieces:
        IMAGES[lookup[piece]] = p.transform.scale(p.image.load("images/" + piece + ".png"), (SQ_SIZE, SQ_SIZE))
```

Then I had to change the way I drew the pieces on the board.

```
def drawPieces(screen, board):
    for r in range(DIMENSION):
        for c in range(DIMENSION):
            piece = board[r][c]
            if piece != 0:  # not empty square
                screen.blit(IMAGES[piece], p.Rect(c * SQ_SIZE, r * SQ_SIZE, SQ_SIZE, SQ_SIZE))
```

Just got rid of the `if piece != '--` with `if piece != 0` and it work. I also changed the variable in the function call of `drawGameState` to `gs.board` to `gs.compute_board`.